# Close children form that was shown in background thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I have 2 forms, first - main, and second children, that opened from thred. I need that on opening children form if child form is already opened close it and show only one child form.

Main form:

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void showChildForms(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        createThread();
        createThread();
        createThread();
    }

    private  void createThread()
    {
        var t = new Thread(
               () =>
               {
                   this.Invoke(new Action(delegate
                   {

                       showForm();
                   }));
               }
               );
        t.IsBackground = true;
        t.Start();
    }

    private void showForm()
    {
        var form2 = new ChildForm();
        form2.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

Children form:

```
public partial class ChildForm : Form
{
    public ChildForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, the vote for most unnecessary use of threading goes to you.

Comment: I have two winforms application(A, B). A call B with some parameters and B open some form. Thread I use that A do not wait while B in progress. In example you can see application B.

Comment: This isn't really clear to me. I was thinking that there is only one application?

Comment: Check out my post it will close if the form is already opened as you said

Comment: I explain why I use thread to [James](http://stackoverflow.com/users/82586/james). Task what I try solved applies one application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If my understanding is right.

If it didn't meet ur need please comment your requirement more clearly

In your main form

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{

 var form2 = new ChildForm();

public MainForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void showChildForms(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    createThread();
    createThread();
    createThread();
}

private  void createThread()
{
    var t = new Thread(
           () =>
           {
               this.Invoke(new Action(delegate
               {

                   showForm();
               }));
           }
           );
    t.IsBackground = true;
    t.Start();
}

private void showForm()
{

     Form res = new Form();

        foreach (Form form in Application.OpenForms)
        {
            if (form.Text == "Form2")//or form.Name u can use how you are assigning in form2 
            {
                res = form;
                break;
            }
        }

        res.Close();

         // Do what ever.The above part will close the previous instances of the Forms.

}
}
```

Comment: What the difference in using a thread instead of calling showForm directly? You execute showForm in the main Thread here also.

Comment: I tried [explain](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20377050/close-children-form-that-was-shown-in-background-thread/20377365?noredirect=1#comment30423298_20377050)

Answer (score 0):

First, your question is not really clear to me. But..
A simple approach is to share a bool between them.
Another hint: dispose always your form when you are finish with it.
The thread here, is really waste of resources.. you should overthinking your approach.

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public bool ChildIsOpen {get; set;}

    private void showChildForms(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        createThread();
        createThread();
        createThread();
    }

    private  void createThread()
    {
        if(ChildIsOpen)
             return;
        var t = new Thread(
               () =>
               {
                   this.Invoke(new Action(delegate
                   {

                       showForm();
                   }));
               }
               );
        t.IsBackground = true;
        t.Start();
    }

    private void showForm()
    {
        using (ChildForm childForm = new ChildForm())
        {
            childForm .Load += (o, args) => ChildIsOpen = true;
            childForm .Closed += (o, args) => ChildIsOpen = false;
            childForm .ShowDialog();
        }
    }
}
```

Children form (unchanged):

```
public partial class ChildForm : Form
{
    public ChildForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

}
```

Comment: It's no more static. The `ChildIsOpen` is reset correctly, read my code.